# VLookUp between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have 2 sheets, they both have sales order, so I have to do a VLookUp, since the salesorders are placed differently in sheet2 than in sheet 1.

I know I have to do a VLookUp, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In which column is the data you want to transfer from one sheet to another?

Comment: I need all the data from sheet2, so all the the columns. From sheet2 to sheet1: Column B = D, C=E, D=F, E=G, G=O, H=P, I=Q, J=AA, K=AB, L=AC, M=AD, N=AE.

Comment: This is really basic, searching this site will give you tons of answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) you need to provide the *column_num* of the value to return. In your case, you can use a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to find the correct column using the headers.

In Sheet1!B2, use this formula,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(--RIGHT($A2, 9), Sheet2!$A:$N, MATCH(B$1, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0), FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT($A2, 9), Sheet2!$A:$N, MATCH(B$1, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0), FALSE), ""))
```

It is unclear on whether the values in Sheet2!A:A are text-that-look-like-numbers or actual numbers. The above will look at both. If your system using a semi-colon as a list separator instead of a comma then that would be,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(--RIGHT($A2; 9); Sheet2!$A:$N; MATCH(B$1; Sheet2!$1:$1; 0); FALSE); IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT($A2; 9); Sheet2!$A:$N; MATCH(B$1; Sheet2!$1:$1; 0); FALSE); ""))
```

Fill this both right and down. Each formula will try and match the header label in Sheet1 with a header label in Sheet2 in order to return the correct value.

The [RIGHT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267EE-9AFA-4639-A02B-F19E1786CF2F) will strip off the `S-` from the Sagsnr values in Sheet1.

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) will check for a true number and then as text-that-looks-like-a-number. If neither can be matched, it simply returns a zero-length string (e.g. `""`).

[image: VLOOKUP with MATCH for column_num]

Comment: I don't know if it's just me being dumb, but when I try to do the formula in Sheet1!B2, I get an error. "This formula you typed contains an error. • For information about fixing common formula problems, click help. • To get assistance in entering a function, click Function Wizard (Formulas tab, Function library group). • If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quatation mark (')

Comment: Do you other formulas use a comma (e.g. `,`) or a semi-colon (e.g. `;`) between parameters?

Comment: Jeeped, I really appreciate your help, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't get any data from sheet2. When I use the furmula with semi-colon, I don't get an error, but I don't get any data either.

Comment: Hi again, I've found out myself, but I used some of the information you gave me. So +1.